# ClusterIP not reachable within the Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, containers, devops, kubernetes-service

I'm struggling with kubernates configurations. What I want to get it's just to reach a deployment within the cluster. The cluster is on my dedicated server and I'm deploying it by using Kubeadm.

My nodes:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
k8s-master    Ready    master   9d    v1.19.3
k8s-worker1   Ready    <none>   9d    v1.19.3
```

I've a deployment  running (nginx basic example)

```
$ kubectl get deployment
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-deployment   2/2     2            2           29m
```

I've created a service

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   9d
my-service   ClusterIP   10.106.109.94   <none>        80/TCP    20m
```

The YAML file for my service is the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-deployment
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

Now I should expect, if I run `curl 10.106.109.94:80` on my `k8s-master` to get the http answer.. but what I got is:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.106.109.94 port 80: Connection refused
```

I've tried with `NodePort` as well and with `targetPort` and `nodePort` but the result is the same.

Comment: From where did you curl? From a Node or Pod within the cluster?

Comment: From the node master

Comment: Where are you running your cluster (cloud, on prem, OS ver) ? How did you bootstrap it (kubeadm etc)? . Please update your yaml files into the question.

Comment: on bare metal & with kubeadm, Thanks you, I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The cluster ip can not be reachable from outside of your cluster that means you will not get any response from the host machine that host your k8s cluster as this ip is not a part of your machine or any other machine rather than its a cluster ip which is used by your cluster CNI network like flunnel,weave.
So to get your services accessible from the outside or atleast from the host machine you have to change the type of your service like NodePort,LoadBalancer,K8s port-forward.

If you can change the service type NodePort then you will get response with any of your host machine ip and the  allocated nodeport.
For example,if your k8s-master is 192.168.x.x and nodePort is 33303 then you can get response by

```
curl http://192.168.x.x:33303
or
curl http://worker_node_ip:33303
```

if your cluster is in locally installed, then you can install [metalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to get the privilege of load balancer.

You can also use port-forward to get your service accessible from the host that has kubectl client with k8s cluster access.

```
kubectl port-forward svc/my-service 80:80

kubectl -n namespace port-forward svc/service_name Port:Port
```

Comment: I tried to switch to node port and from the master I can't curl the pod on worker node… I just can with the pod on master node (with port 80 and not that as NodePort (31303))